# How to change path parameters before passing to controllers in spring?

Tags: spring

What is the best way to change path parameter (may be using interceptor) before passing it to controllers ? I am using spring mvc.
Right now, i am adding an extra parameter to get the job done, and checking for that in the controller, but i would rather change the parameter and not change anything in the controller

Comment: I think you can use AOP for this, you create an advice method around the controller methods

Comment: i don't want to touch the controller class, is that possible ? righ tnow i am trying with handlerinterceptor,

Comment: Yes it is possible, here are some examples https://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-and-aop-with-spring-boot-starter-aop 
And you can check out the docs of AspectJ. if it doesn't work, tell me and I will give an example from my code. We are basically using it to catch exceptions thrown from services to controllers.